# javascript tabs as I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: current status]

i have a problem here.I have two tabs here 'LB" and "medalTally' . I need to display the first tab info by default as the page loads and it should hide as I click the second tab.I have some codes for it.
can anyone help me where exactly am I making the mistake.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _this = $('.tab a:first')
  var block = _this.attr('href');
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    if (block == "#leaderboard") {
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#login').hide();
    }
    if (block == "#login") {
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#leaderboard').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

fiddle link for it : https://jsfiddle.net/Zedhmem/ju0xr8of/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just added one line in javascript :

```
$('.tab.active a').click();
```

It will click on active tab on `$(document).ready`

https://jsfiddle.net/ju0xr8of/7/

Comment: Also,can we have the same leaderboard when I click the medal tally tab.Ofcourse ,I will have differnt values in the table,which I will take care of. I tried to copy the content of the leadership class of html page within login div id

Answer (score 1):

you can only insert **document ready inside open click** event

**I try to your second bug resolve.** when you can click second div then active class not there . that are issue resolve  below  Code

First remove `active` class after then add active class when click div .

**Script**

```
$(document).find('.active').removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().addClass( "active" );
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/wwvrpqkL/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab a').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
          var _this = $(this);
     var block = _this.attr('href');
     if(block == "#leaderboard"){
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#login').hide();
             $(document).find('.active').removeClass("active");
             $(this).parent().addClass( "active" );
     }
     if(block == "#login"){
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#leaderboard').hide();
             $(document).find('.active').removeClass("active");
             $(this).parent().addClass( "active" );
     }
    });

 $('.tab.active a').click(); // Default open
   });
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*--------------------
Leaderboard
--------------------*/
.leaderboard {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
          transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  width: 285px;
  height: 308px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
  display:none;
}
.leaderboard h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 13px 18px;
}
.leaderboard h1 svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.leaderboard ol {
  counter-reset: leaderboard;
}
.leaderboard ol li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::before, .leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -9px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
          transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
 <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard</a></li>
 <li class="tab"><a href="#login">MedalTally</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
 <div id="signup">
   
  <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
    <h1>
   <svg class="ico-cup">
     <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
   </svg>
   Leaderboard
    </h1>
    <ol>
   <li>
     <mark>Jerry Wood</mark>
     <small>315</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
     <small>301</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
     <small>292</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
     <small>245</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
     <small>203</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
     <small>203</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
     <small>245</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
     <small>203</small>
   </li>
    
    </ol>
  </div>


  <svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
   C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
   C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
   c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
   c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
   c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
   c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
   c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
   c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
   c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
   C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
   c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
   L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
   c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
   C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
   C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
   c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
     </symbol>
  </svg>
    </div>

 <div id="login">
   <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

   <form action="/" method="post">

  <div class="field-wrap">
   <label>
     Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>

    <div class="field-wrap">
   <label>
     Password<span class="req">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>

    <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

    <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

   </form>

 </div>

 </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Makes sense. Also,can we have the same leaderboard when I click the medal tally tab.Ofcourse ,I will have differnt values in the table,which I will take care of.@Sumit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing the line of code to display the first tab info by default.  I added it below right after document.ready

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#leaderboard").fadeIn(); //This displays the first tab info by default**       
  var _this = $('.tab a:first')
  var block = _this.attr('href');
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    if (block == "#leaderboard") {
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#login').hide();
    }
    if (block == "#login") {
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#leaderboard').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:none` on page load. On you can remove it in css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab a').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var _this = $(this);
     var block = _this.attr('href');
     if(block == "#leaderboard"){
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#login').hide();
     }
     if(block == "#login"){
      $(block).fadeIn();
      $('#leaderboard').hide();
     }
    });
   });
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*--------------------
Leaderboard
--------------------*/
.leaderboard {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
          transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  width: 285px;
  height: 308px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
}
.leaderboard h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 13px 18px;
}
.leaderboard h1 svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.leaderboard ol {
  counter-reset: leaderboard;
}
.leaderboard ol li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::before, .leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -9px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
          transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before, .leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
 <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard</a></li>
 <li class="tab"><a href="#login">MedalTally</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
 <div id="signup">
   
  <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
    <h1>
   <svg class="ico-cup">
     <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
   </svg>
   Leaderboard
    </h1>
    <ol>
   <li>
     <mark>Jerry Wood</mark>
     <small>315</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
     <small>301</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
     <small>292</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
     <small>245</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
     <small>203</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
     <small>203</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
     <small>245</small>
   </li>
   <li>
     <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
     <small>203</small>
   </li>
    
    </ol>
  </div>


  <svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
   C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
   C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
   c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
   c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
   c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
   c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
   c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
   c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
   c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
   C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
   c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
   L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
   c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
   C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
   C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
   c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
     </symbol>
  </svg>
    </div>

 <div id="login">
   <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

   <form action="/" method="post">

  <div class="field-wrap">
   <label>
     Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>

    <div class="field-wrap">
   <label>
     Password<span class="req">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>

    <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

    <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

   </form>

 </div>

 </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also,can we have the same leaderboard when I click the medal tally tab.Ofcourse ,I will have differnt values in the table,which I will take care of. I tried to copy the content of the leadership class of html page within login div id

Comment: @ShivamSharma You need the same leader board for your other tab too? Simply Copy and pasting the content of the leadership class should work i guess.

Comment: Thanks.Yeah it will contain different values.It will be weekly leaderboard

Comment: @ShivamSharma what about your login div? That div will be replaced with your weekly Leaderboard?

Comment: let the div remain as it is.We will change the content within it and replace it within content of the leaderboard.What if I copy the content within signup class i.e the entire leaderboard class within the login class

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger click for the first tab and that should do the trick

```
$('.tab a:first').trigger("click");
```

Look at the update working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/ju0xr8of/9/

Comment: Thank you so much.Makes sense. Also,can we have the same leaderboard when I click the medal tally tab.Ofcourse ,I will have differnt values in the table,which I will take care of. I tried to copy the content of the leadership class of html page within login div id.